# TrueCrypt transfer to Drobo is very slow

Tags: file-transfer, truecrypt, speed, usb-storage

**Problem**

I'm getting very slow 2 MB/s transfer speeds. I have a computer with a 5.4k RPM spinning disk drive connected to the motherboard via SATA 1 then through USB 3.0 to a Drobo disk array also with USB 3.0. Over many hours, my average transfer speed is only 2.6 MB/s for sequential reads/writes.. To throw a wrench in the mix, this is related to TrueCrypt encryption for the external hard drive. I don't see the same problem when transferring to a non-encrypted volume.

I found [this](http://www.tested.com/tech/pcs/457172-why-storage-drive-speeds-dont-hit-their-theoretical-limits/) great website with info on theoretical limits and I believe my limiting factor is my computer hard drive at around 50 MB/s since [this](http://www.storagereview.com/ssd_vs_hdd) website claims HDDs can range from 50-120 MB/s. Keep in mind, I'm only getting 2 MB/s, not 50 MB/s.

The other potential limiting factors are:
SATA 1 = 150 MB/s
USB 3.0 = 625 MB/s
Disk array = ??? (I'm assuming a lot)

**Problem Summary**

Setup is:
Hard drive > SATA 1 > Truecrypt > USB 3.0 > USB 3.0 > Disk array providing only 

Only getting speeds of 2 MB/s because of TrueCrypt

**What could be wrong?**
I'm guessing there is a ton of overhead when pulling the data over USB for TrueCrypt to decrypt it. Is there a way to make this faster?

**Additional Info**

I'm currently getting ~2MB/s going from the encrypted to my computer. This is my main concern.

Drobo(encrypted) to Computer - ~2 MB/s
Computer to Drobo(encrypted) -  ~20 MB/s
Drobo(non-encrypted) to Computer - ~60 MB/s
Computer to Drobo(non-encrypted) - ~80 MB/s

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with drobo, sounds similar to a raid array? Does copying a similarly large amount of data (NOT through truecrypt) *from* the same partition *to* the same usb disk/array go at 50MB/s consistently (or some speed >2MB/s)? Is the "non-encrypted volume" you mentioned in the Q on the same disk? Could there be a very slow drive in your array?

Comment: Yes, a Drobo is basically a RAID array with proprietary data management software on top. It's using a concept called thin provisioning which allows me to present two 8TB drives to Windows but in actuality, I only have 10 TB available. I don't think that's the problem but it doesn't hurt to say it. (I have plenty of space). I'm going to add some more information to the end of the original question.

Comment: Hmm, 10 != 16... sounds like a lot of data compression happening on the Drobo, is that what it does? You know encryption (like truecrypt) writes data that is nearly random, and random data does not compress well at all, maybe that could be causing some delays in Drobo attempting compression. Tried copying a big truecrypt container file to the Drobo, not while running truecrypt but just copying the file?

Comment: The Drobo does not use compression but I think you're on to something. It's looking like the data storage algorithms on the Drobo coulb ebe the problem I'm able to write a file to the encrypted drive and then immediately pull is back at 30 MB/s (which seems to be my Computer's max write speed).  I cannot do that with a file that's been on the drive for a while. To add to that, I can pull the first file at 30 MB/s but when I try to grab another file with a new thread, it drops both to ~2MB/s. I guess I'm maxing out the Drobo's random reads across multiple drives.

Answer (score 1):

Well...after massive research into disk throughput it was resolved by accident. Apparently, if I first copy the files from my encrypted drive to a new folder in the ***same*** encrypted drive it fixes it.

The encrypted to encrypted move is instantaneous since I'm on the same disk. It's then followed by a 30 MB/s transfer to my computer which is 15x faster than before so I'm happy.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with TrueCrypt, Drobo, or something crazy like Windows indexing. I'm going to blame Drobo because they refused to help me with this problem...jerks.

Comment: +1 for "jerks"! Things can get very complicated with encryption + raid-type setups, might've even been double-reading & writing to a drive somehow. FYI, there are file-based encryption methods (at least in linux) that can encrypt individual files as a group (an encrypted folder/tree), that may take up less space than truecrypt's big container files, but reveal some info on # of files & size. Or zipping/compressing before encrypting... even 10TB may eventually look small